# How to pass data to new tab using state in angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass data from one component to another using state, but if I right-click on anchor and select open link in a new tab, I am unable to get data in the second component while if I have a simple click on the anchor I get data in second component

FirstComponent.html

```
<a [state]="{'id': 1}" [routerLink]="['../SecondComponent']">Go</a>
```

SecondComponent.ts

```
this._router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.id;
```

This could not help. 
[How to pass data using state when opening a url in a new tab in Angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62949586/how-to-pass-data-using-state-when-opening-a-url-in-a-new-tab-in-angular-8)

Comment: Do you use `NgRx` in your app?

Comment: No, i am not using

Answer (score 0):

```
goToYourComponent() {
 this.router.navigate(['/yourRoute'], { state: { id: 1 } });
}
```

and in your target component you can get it:

```
 const navState = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
```

Comment: I want to open by right-clicking on anchor and selecting the open link in a new tab

Comment: then I think you cant pass state but you can pass query params ```<a [href]="'http://example.com/link?id=' + 10"> open link </a> ``` Or
```<a routerLink="/testPage " [queryParams]="{ id: '10' }" >
  open link 
</a>```

Comment: @MohammadBabaei the above is not a good approach when you have the object to pass to the testPage route component.